# Removing parts of the image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, bitwise-operators, mask

I have an image and I want to simply remove(or mask) parts of it with OpenCV. this is my original image :
[image]

And I want to remove a circle on its center via this image mask : 
[image]

I use this command in my code which from the tutorials I read should work and black out a circle in the center of my original image :

```
img = cv2.bitwise_not(imgOriginal,imgOriginal,mask=imgMask)
```

but the result I get is the image below, in fact instead of removing the masked parts, it just inverts blacks and whites:
[image]

I'll appreciate if  you can help me on finding a way to properly mask(or remove) the parts I want.
Thanks

Comment: "it just inverts blacks and whites" -- Of course it does, you told it to do a bitwise not (i.e. invert) only in the areas where the mask is white, and leave the rest untouched.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//given source, mask and destination Mat images with same size
cv::subtract(img, mask, dst);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set pixels to the background color using a mask, like this:

```
img.setTo(Scalar::all(0),mask);
```