# detect and remove text from photo

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network, object-detection, opencv, python

I have a dataset of about 2000 pictures of banana plants that I need to check if a CNN can spot the difference between them.
The problem is that some of the photos that were taken include their tag in the photo.

is there a way to detect and remove those somehow?

I have tried masking parts of the images, but every mask is suitable only for a few photos and I cannot apply it for all photos

The thing I tried, using cv2 with python, but didn't help:

masking the image:
[Removing parts of the image with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965333/removing-parts-of-the-image-with-opencv)

removing text from the image:
[OpenCV - Remove text from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592055/opencv-remove-text-from-image)

the classes are A/B/C/D
pictures:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. everything in the background is different. why are the labels a problem?

Comment: Will it be easier just to extract leaves and do the actual comparison without having all that extra noise?

Comment: @Piglet the problem is that although the background is different, each category has its label within the photo, that not going to affect the results?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's be honest, we likely have a problem with the initial question. It is enough to have a plant to compare with another plant (or to track the process of growing), so no need to deal with any secondary object on the photo.

Also, because of the specific color it might be easier to segment a plant and have all the required details for any additional analysis:

[image]

The example I have allows to provide a notification when a strawberry is "ready".

[image]

Multi-color segmentation might be quite helpful in this particular case. Here is a [complete demo](https://youtu.be/LtVoo61heS0)

Sorry, no code to provide, not using OpenCV.